# On-Device Data Saving Blocked By Default in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, data-storage

I'm auditing a site and have come across something that I've never seen before - by default my browser isn't allowing this site to save data on my device. Normally, I would expect this to be allowed unless I intentionally disallow it. I also can't find any documentation that specifically talks about this.

**2 main questions:**

- Why might a browser prevent a site from storing data on a device without the user's instruction?
- Could a bad reputation, or an IP appearing on blacklists cause this behavior?

[image: Device storage icon in chrome, shown in URL bar with a cross through it]
[image: Tooltip indicating that a site isn't allowed to save data on your device]